# Where can I find online resources about writing a visual novel?

Tags: resources, branching-narrative

I have read/played quite a few visual novels and am interested in the process of creating one.

**Where can I find (preferrably free) online resources, such as *How-To-Write* or styleguide articles and blogs, about writing a visual novel?**

The main reason for asking specifically about a *visual* novel is that I am having problems with the idea of creating a [branched storyline](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/32467/are-there-tools-that-can-aid-an-author-in-writing-a-branching-storyline) and would like to see what common ways are for creating such a story.

Furthermore the way of presenting the story has always reminded me of theater and I would like to see whether visual novel authors use different formatting or descriptions when writing than text-only novel authors.

The fact that players can choose a path and that I have seen different ways of presenting these options is also fascinating, because some visual novels were giving the complete text a character would say while others would summarize the main content and I am not sure whether there are guidelines for what way should be preferred.

Comment: This sort of thing (https://forums.fuwanovel.net)? It's not a type of writing I know enough about to post a proper answer, but that seemed to fit.

Comment: @ItWasLikeThatWhenIGotHere At a first glance that seems to fit, thanks. I will take a closer look later today as I don't have the time right now.

Comment: You need to learn Japanese and Russian. Visual Novels are very popular in those cultures, and the creators discuss their craft mainly in those languages. You won't get far with English here.

Answer (score 1):

I would look at movie scripts for ideas on how to layout the dialog and then look at how to write a book outline and use that format for keeping track of your plot branches. Finally character sheets to do detailed write ups about your characters. Hope that helps.